# Bootstrapping to Fisher test

Tags: r

I try to understand bootstrap resampling provided by function "boot" in package: boot
So that my example:

```r
x<-matrix(c(1,4,11,2),2,2,dimnames = list(c("Acinar", "Solid"),c("Few","Many")))
fishes <- function(d,f) {
    d=as.matrix(x)
        fisher.exact(d)
}
boot(x, fishes, R=1000)
```

So I received that error:

> Error in t.star[r, ] <- res[[r]] :    incorrect number of subscripts
>   on matrix

What wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a contingency table, bootstrapping that does not work. You need to bootstrap upstream, that is subsample your observations, make the 2x2 table and test:

```
data = rbind(
data.frame(x=rep(c("Few","Many"),c(1,11)),y="Acinar"),
data.frame(x=rep(c("Few","Many"),c(4,2)),y="Solid"))

table(data)

      y
x      Acinar Solid
  Few       1     4
  Many     11     2
```

You also need to define what to return from the fisher test, otherwise `boot` will throw an error:

```
library(boot)
fishes <- function(d,ind){
FT = fisher.test(table(d[ind,]))
c(FT$p.value,FT$estimate)
}

B = boot(data, fishes, R=100)
B

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = data, statistic = fishes, R = 100)


Bootstrap Statistics :
      original      bias    std. error
t1* 0.02170868 0.057475511  0.14698585
t2* 0.05873784 0.003507629  0.09223193
```

You can get a confidence interval of the odds ratio:

```
boot.ci(B,type="perc",index = 2)
BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
Based on 100 bootstrap replicates

CALL : 
boot.ci(boot.out = B, type = "perc", index = 2)
```

Comment: HOW to report the results here?

Comment: depends on why you need to bootstrap in the first place? I guess you can report a 95% confidence interval of the odds ratio, see edit

Comment: Is it okay to report like this—— The original estimate of the p value derived from bootstrapping with 100
iterations is 0.02170868 < 0.05, which suggests that the null hypothesis of no difference is rejected.

Comment: hey this is a statistics question and you should ask it on cross-validated. the bootstrap does not tell you the p-value. You don't need the bootstrap to tell you 0.02170868, it comes from running fisher.test on the original data